# twitter update using TWRequest gives 403 error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, twitter, ios6

i'm using the following code to tweet in user's timeline using the iOS 5 twitter API

// Create an account store object.
    ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];

```
// Create an account type that ensures Twitter accounts are retrieved.
ACAccountType *accountType =  [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

// Request access from the user to use their Twitter accounts.
[accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) 
 {
     if(granted) 
     {
         // Get the list of Twitter accounts.
         NSArray *accountsArray = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

         // For the sake of brevity, we'll assume there is only one Twitter account present.
         // You would ideally ask the user which account they want to tweet from, if there is more than one Twitter account present.
         // Grab the initial Twitter account to tweet from.
         ACAccount *twitterAccount = [accountsArray objectAtIndex:buttonIndex];
         // Create a request, which in this example, posts a tweet to the user's timeline.
         // This example uses version 1 of the Twitter API.
         // This may need to be changed to whichever version is currently appropriate.


         TWRequest *postRequest = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json"] parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"hello this is a tweet" forKey:@"status"] requestMethod:TWRequestMethodPOST];

         // Set the account used to post the tweet.
         [postRequest setAccount:twitterAccount];

         // Perform the request created above and create a handler block to handle the response.
         [postRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) 
          {

              NSString *output = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [urlResponse statusCode]];
              [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(TweetStatus:) withObject:output waitUntilDone:NO];
          }];
     }
 }];
```

i've been using this method for more than a month now for testing the application and it used to work fine with no problems.

**few weeks a goo it started to return a 403 error in the following method.**

```
[postRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) 
          {

              NSString *output = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [urlResponse statusCode]];
              [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(TweetStatus:) withObject:output waitUntilDone:NO];
          }];
```

it gives the following error:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)" UserInfo=0x1f8b3250 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json, NSUnderlyingError=0x1ed19f90 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -1012
```

i've searched a lot and could not find any solution or real cause to this problem.

a few notes to keep in mind that might help understanding the problem:

- the application is used for testing which means that we used the twitter sharing and mentions a lot with other users.
- the sharing content is not always the same so no duplication issue should occur as we were clearing the timeline frequently.

thanks

Comment: Which method is causing the error? Accessing account or posting the tweet? And what else does the error say?

Comment: have you tried using other text which are not already posted on your account?

Comment: yes i tried with different text

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> i've been using this method for more than a month now for testing the application and it used to work fine with no problems.

I think that's the issue right there. this account you are testing might been marked as a spammer by other people.

If you use another account or other phone and the code works, then that's the only explanation my friend.

Good luck

Answer (score 7):

The text you have been trying to tweet must be similar to what has been tweeted by you previously, hence you are getting this error. According to the documentation [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/update), the same text cannot be posted more than once.
[image]

EDIT:

It might also depend on the total number of tweets as mentioned in their website.

Answer (score 4):

I noticed you are using the following URL to post a tweet from your user:

`http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json`

This is using version 1.0 of the Twitter API which is deprecated and slowly will stop working over the next few months

Instead you should try using

`https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json` *(There has been a [recent change to the Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/24239).  You can now **only** call it using HTTPS.)*

This will specify the latest version of the API.

Comment: i changed the link for a problem that may occur in the future. but the problem still exists with some of the twitter accounts! not all of the accounts on testing device.